# Creating a global variable in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to create a global variable from my view controller (inside the class but outside the functions) as follows:

```
var modelData: CustomTabBarController.model   // THE ERROR IS HERE
```

This is how that class is defined:

**CustomTabBarController.swift:**

```
import UIKit

// This class holds the data for my model.
class ModelData {
    var name = "Fred"
    var age = 50
}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    // Instantiate the one copy of the model data that will be accessed
    // by all of the tabs.
    var model = ModelData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
"'model' is not a member type of "CustomTabBarController"
```

How do I declare it so that I can access model?  Thanks.

**Update #1**
Sorry I forgot to mention this:

I need the model data to be the SAME in every tab of the tabbar. For example if I change the age to 51 in the first tab, the second tabbar should retrieve 51. Which would be the correct method above to use it this way?

**Update #2**

I am able to create the variable inside a function with dean's suggestion:

```
func setupModelData()
{
  var modelData = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model
}
```

However this does not work, since I need to access the modelData from other functions.  When I attempt to move this line outside of the function as follows:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
 var modelData = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model
...
```

I receive the error:

```
Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> FirstViewController' has no member 'tabBarController'
```

Comment: why don't you create a singleton then? much better than a random global variable.

Comment: Thank you Holex, please see answer below.  I ended up using your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up following holex's suggestion of creating a shared class (singleton):

```
import UIKit
class ModelData: NSObject {
    static let shared: ModelData = ModelData()
    var name = "Fred"
    var age = 50
}
```

**Writing in first view: Set age to 51:**

```
ModelData.shared.age = 51
```

**Reading in second view: Get age of 51**

```
let age = ModelData.shared.age
```

Comment: best answer i got

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you truly want a global variable (i.e. a single instance of ModelData shared between all your view controllers) or an instance variable which is public, so I'll try to answer both :)

**1) global model**

This line attempts to get the model property from the `CustomerTabBarController` *class* - i.e. if you made multiple tab bar controllers they would all use the same model.

```
var modelData: CustomTabBarController.model
```

If this is what you want, then you need to change this line to include the static keyword.

```
static var model = ModelData()
```

However, this almost certainly isn't what you're after.

**2) shared instance variable**

This means that the model is part of each *instance* of `CustomTabBarController`. Here, you would need to change the line which is throwing the error to be something like this:

```
var modelData: myCustomTabBarController.model
```

Without knowing more about your architecture, I can't help you get hold of your tab bar controller instance, but something like this might work (inside other view controllers):

```
var modelData = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model
```

Comment: dean, thanks.  I am trying to use this line: var modelData = (self.tabBarController as! CustomTabBarController).model     But I am getting this error "Value of type NSObject FirstViewController has no member tabBarController"   I am attempting to use that line on the first tab.   The first tab is also embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: That looks like `FirstViewController` isn't a subclass of `UIViewController`?

Comment: It does inherit UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Comment: When I try this (with a typo to replicate the error message) I get `value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'tabBarControllerr'` - your error says NSObject but mine has ViewController, which tells me something funny is going on with your definition of FirstViewController

Comment: The exact error I get it : "Value of type '(NSObject) -> () -> FirstViewController' has no member 'tabBarController'"

Comment: Dean, check out update #2 above from your suggestion.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`model` is an instance variable.

Either create an instance of `CustomTabBarController`

```
var modelData =  CustomTabBarController().model
```

Or declare `model` as class variable

```
static var model = ModelData()

...

var modelData = CustomTabBarController.model
```

---

However to use `ModelData` as a single global variable with the two members, use a struct rather than a class and declare the members as static.

```
struct ModelData {
    static var name = "Fred"
    static var age = 50
}
```

You can access the name from everywhere for example

```
let name = ModelData.name
```

and there is no need to create an extra variable in another class.

---

An – instance based –  alternative is a singleton

```
struct ModelData {

    static let shared = ModelData()

    var name = "Fred"
    var age = 50
}
```

and use it

```
let name = ModelData.shared.name
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian.  Quick question, I need the model data to be the same in every tab.  For example if I change the age to 51 in the first tab, the second tabbar should retrieve 51.  Which would be the correct method above to use it this way?